# Export Power Flows with connection data

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps, dynamics-365

Is there any way to export custom REST connector or already exisiting Power Flows with the connection data within from Microsoft Power Apps? It seems each connection has to be configured manually and when switching between environments all of the connection options must be defined again. Can the final Power Flows be exported as JSON or other file-based option? I’m still searching for a solution to find and replace connection data to switch between the test and productive instance of applications I want to connect to faster.

Is there another solution to migrate Power Flows with the connection data to another environment or even instance in Microsoft Power Apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Connection References**. Create a single Dataverse connection reference and give it a distinct name. Deploy it (unmanaged) on all environments. On every environment edit this connection reference and setup the connection for it. (This is basically a one time step.)

Now make shure your cloud flows only use this unique connection reference. Every Dataverse action should only use this reference. (There is one exeption where we still need the legacy Dataverse connection.) Do not forget cleaning up obsolete connections associated to your flows.

See [MS Docs - Use a connection reference in a solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/data-platform/create-connection-reference).